# Which is better jplayer or jwplayer?

Tags: javascript, jplayer

I need to make a video slideshow( slides to contain embedded video players and must play mp4 files), and I am kind of confused what would be the best free solution I can use? jplayer and jwplayer both seem good, but I can't find any comparisons between them, so I want some expert opinions and user experiences on these two. Also if there are any other free and open source solutions you can recommend, i am all ears ;)

My requirements are: The player must be html5 with fallback to flash.
Should support mp4 files as well as flv. 
Should also have the ability to double as an audio player(mp3) along with video capabilities. Should be lightweight and customizable easily in terms of looks.

Comment: It doesn't fit your requirements. But for other projects you could look at http://mozillapopcorn.org/ too.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using JWPlayer for the past few years and while I'm intrigued by JPlayer it is missing some features I need.

Based on my initial investigation, JPlayer is currently missing 2 key features as compared to JWPlayer - RTMP streaming and control of video scaling if the player and video are of different sizes.

RTMP streaming is straight forward - Google it if you need to. There's also an implementation waiting to be merged into JPlayer on Github that has been taking it's time to get into the main code base.

Video scaling is important when dealing with user supplied content where you don't know the video aspect ratio. On the other hand, you probably do know the size you want the player to be and likely also have an opinion on how you want the video to be presented within the player.

As far as skinning and MP3, I don't see anything to differentiate the two - you should have no problem with MP3s on either as well as complete control over the skin.

So today, the decision is more about a young, open source project versus a more mature, commercial project unless the points I mentioned above are relevant to you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend jPlayer as it is open source and free. The API is a little cumbersome, but nothing too serious.

JWPlayer's free version overlays a watermark on the video.